# Spring Project inside EJB project

Tags: spring, ejb, web-container

I have an old java EE project which uses EJB and CDI and runs on Tomcat web container.
I then recently created a project using spring core. Is it ok to use the spring within EJB project?

If yes, then how component lifecycle works for both. Will there be a conflict?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spring library inside the EJB project. But what is the use case?
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-ejb
https://dzone.com/articles/ejb-30-and-spring-25

Comment: I have library written in spring, now I want to use it inside the old EJB project